# Encontrar suma total con PHP

Tags: php

logre resolver el problema anterior en cuanto hallar la manera de vincular la suma total de ventas de los usuarios nivel 2 y 3 el conflicto que tengo ahora es para hallar el resultado para el nivel 1 ya que este nivel se toma como empresa , necesito hallar el resultado de todas las ventas de las oficinas pertenecientes a ella , la tabla cliente y usuario se relacionan con el campo por parte del cliente usuario_id y con usuario idusuario ambas tablas tienen los campos oficina y empresa en la tabla cliente almaceno las ventas de cada usuario a continuación adjunto el código con el que intente dicho proceso pero no me sale ningún resulta en nivel 1 me queda en 0

```
if ($rol == 1 ) {

$sql = "SELECT SUM(prima_total) prima, usuario_id FROM cliente WHERE usuario_id = $iduser";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo  number_format( $fila['prima']);
  }
```

Comment: Puedes dar mas informacion?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la columna que determina el nivel? Debes ponerla en el criterio de la consulta, algo como `WHERE ... AND laColumnaDelNivel=1`

Comment: @A.Cedano acertada tu corrección , puede observar que era lo que me faltaba

Answer (score 0):

En la cláusula `WHERE` puedes usar `AND` o cualquier otro operador permitido, como bien indica el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html):

> In the `WHERE` expression, you can use any of the functions and
> operators that MySQL supports, except for aggregate (group) functions.
> See Section 9.5, “Expressions”, and Chapter 12, Functions and
> Operators.
>
> ---
>
> En la expresión `WHERE`, puede usar cualquiera de las funciones y
> operadores que admite MySQL, excepto las funciones agregadas (de
> grupo). Consulte la [Sección 9.5, “Expresiones”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html) y el [Capítulo 12,
> Funciones y operadores](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html).

Significa que para este caso puedes agregar el criterio que te falta usando el operador lógico `AND`, por ejemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(prima_total) prima, usuario_id FROM cliente WHERE usuario_id = $iduser" AND laColumnaQueIdentificalElNivel=1;
```

### Advertencia sobre la seguridad

Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*, deberías considerar el uso de consultas preparadas para blindar el código.